# How to use custom self signed certificates in Neo4j (instead of snakeoil.cert)?

Tags: ssl, neo4j, r-neo4j

Recently I ran into the problem of generating a custom certificate that does not bind to 0.0.0.0 in Neo4j. It turns out that Neo4j - in contrast to the documentation - expects DER certificates for both the public and private key.

I will post lessons learned in respons to this question.

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 3.0 this has been changed.

- Open up `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf` and uncomment and change the following line:

  ```
    # dbms.directories.certificates=/PATH/TO/YOUR/CERTIFICATES
  ```
- Make sure that directory contains you certificate files named `neo4j.key` and `neo4j.cert`.
- Make sure the files can be written by neo4j.

If you're using only `.pem` files, you can just rename those to `.cert` and `.key`, they're all plain text files, `.pem` is just an extension.

See the [reference](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/#config_dbms.directories.certificates)

> Directory for storing certificates to be used by Neo4j for TLS connections.
>
> Certificates are stored in the certificates directory, and are called `neo4j.key` and `neo4j.cert`.

Answer (score 1):

sudo vi /etc/neo4j/neo4j-server.properties

```
uncomment org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
check: org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.enabled=true
check: org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=7473
change: org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.cert.location=/var/ssl/neo4j/server.crt
change: org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.key.location=/var/ssl/neo4j/server.key
```

now set up access to https
note: both the private key and the certificate need to be in DER format

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 4096
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.pem
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 4096
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.pem
sudo mkdir -p /var/ssl/neo4j
sudo openssl x509 -outform der -in server.pem -out /var/ssl/neo4j/server.crt
sudo openssl rsa -in server.key -inform PEM -out /var/ssl/neo4j/server.key -outform DER
```

See also [my notes] (http://www.blaeu.com/nl/doku.php/Notes)

Comment: note: make sure the COMMON NAME is the same as the server's ip address, or DNS name.

Comment: You can have server.csr signed by any Certificate Authority. In that case skip line 1, 2, 5. Just use server.csr. After signing, rename the signed certificate to server.pem and continue from line 6.

Comment: See also [use SSL certificates in Neo4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735738/how-to-use-ssl-certificates-in-neo4j-instead-of-self-signed-certificates-or-sna)

Comment: I get `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unrecognized private key format.` with neo4j 4.0.4.