# How to use SSL certificates in Neo4j instead of self-signed certificates (or snakeoil.cert)

Tags: ssl, neo4j, r-neo4j

For a production Neo4j server I need to use a SSL certificate that is not self-signed. I will post lessons learned in the response below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use custom self signed certificates in Neo4j (instead of snakeoil.cert)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716817/how-to-use-custom-self-signed-certificates-in-neo4j-instead-of-snakeoil-cert)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sudo vi /etc/neo4j/neo4j-server.properties

```
uncomment org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
check: org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.enabled=true
check: org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=7473
change: org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.cert.location=/var/ssl/neo4j/server.crt
change: org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.key.location=/var/ssl/neo4j/server.key
```

now set up access to https
note: both the private key and the certificate need to be in DER format

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 4096
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

Have server.csr (the certificate signing request) signed by the Certificate Authority of your choice.

To install the signed certificate, save it as server.pem and execute the following:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/ssl/neo4j
sudo openssl x509 -outform der -in server.pem -out /var/ssl/neo4j/server.crt
sudo openssl rsa -in server.key -inform PEM -out /var/ssl/neo4j/server.key -outform DER
```

Comment: See also [use self-signed certificates in Neo4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716817/how-to-use-custom-self-signed-certificates-in-neo4j-instead-of-snakeoil-cert).

Answer (score 1):

If your neo4j server in public subnet and you want a valid SSL to protect data in transit.

For certificate generation, you can either use native AWS certificates generates or LetsEncrypt.

LetsEncrypt - 
Let's Encrypt is a non-profit certificate authority run by Internet Security Research Group that provides X.509 certificates for Transport Layer Security encryption at no charge.

Install LetsEncrypt-

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y certbot
```

Generate free certificate-

```
$ sudo certbot certonly
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
```

```
# Change group of all letsencrypt files to neo4j
sudo chgrp -R neo4j /etc/letsencrypt/* 
# Make sure all directories and files are group readable.
sudo chmod -R g+rx /etc/letsencrypt/*
```

set up symlinks and the directory structure neo4j expects

```
cd /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
sudo mkdir revoked trusted bak
# Move old generated certificates into a backup directory
sudo mv neo4j.* bak
export MY_DOMAIN=graph.somehost.com
# Configure cert neo4j will use
sudo ln -s /etc/letsencrypt/live/$MY_DOMAIN/fullchain.pem neo4j.cert
# Configure private key neo4j will use
sudo ln -s /etc/letsencrypt/live/$MY_DOMAIN/privkey.pem neo4j.key
# Indicate that this cert is trusted for neo4j
sudo ln -s /etc/letsencrypt/live/$MY_DOMAIN/fullchain.pem trusted/neo4j.cert
```

update Neo4jConf file

```
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address=your.hostname.com
bolt.ssl_policy=default
dbms.ssl.policy.default.base_directory=/var/lib/neo4j/certificates
dbms.ssl.policy.default.allow_key_generation=false
dbms.ssl.policy.default.private_key=/var/lib/neo4j/certificates/neo4j.key
dbms.ssl.policy.default.public_certificate=/var/lib/neo4j/certificates/neo4j.cert
dbms.ssl.policy.default.revoked_dir=/var/lib/neo4j/certificates/revoked
dbms.ssl.policy.default.client_auth=NONE
```

Restart All nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks rvaneijk. It works for me.

To install the signed certificate (Which is obtained from your CA). Keep your pem and key file in same folder.

1. Create certificate in (der format) with extension .crt

sudo openssl x509 -outform der -in your_server_pem.pem -out /.crt

2. Create DER formatted key

sudo openssl rsa -in server.key -inform PEM -out /.key -outform DER

http://www.scriptscoop2.com/t/8f3630652fcd/how-to-use-ssl-certificates-in-neo4j-instead-of-self-signed-certificat.html